# Anyway to get around the comments in comments dilemma

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have some javascript code like this:

```
a = b;
func1();
/*
c = d;
func2();
*/
e = f;
func3();
```

where I've previously commented out a region of code, and then I want to comment out the whole thing

```
/*
a = b;
func1();
/*
c = d;
func2();
*/
e = f;
func3();
*/
```

This will fail, because the first end comment after func2 will short-circuit the wrapping comment, and then the lat */ will be a syntax error.

Other than using inline comments (ie "//") is there a way to avoid this dilemma? If not, there should be...

Comment: nope...........

Comment: Strange question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing tidy, no. Options include (in no particular order):

1. Inline comments.
2. Putting comments around the bit before and the bit after the existing commented-out section.
3. Putting an `if (false) { ... }` around it, so the code is still there, just never run.
4. Actually deleting it and relying on source control for managing the differing bits of code.
5. Some sort of pre-processor (but I don't know of one). *(I* wrote *one, many many years ago, for reasons that are no longer clear to me... :-D I don't still have a copy.)*